# Connected components in a DAG

Tags: java, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I currently have a program that takes a DAG represented by an adjacency list as a system input, converts it into a adjacency matrix and then runs a DFS on the adjacency matrix which outputs the number of connected components.

e.g. the first line represents the total number of nodes with the following lines representing each edge for that node. The following graph..

[image]

corresponds to the following input..

[image]

where the output 3 is the number of connected components.

My issue is that the following code does not work for all graphs, sometimes outputting a larger number of components than should be expected. Any clues to why this is happening would be very useful.

```
public class conComponents {
private Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numNodes;
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            numNodes = sc.nextInt();

            if (numNodes == 0)
                break;

            sc.nextLine();
            int adjMatrix[][] = new int[numNodes][numNodes];

            for (int s = 0; s < numNodes; s++) {
                String[] split = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {

                    if (i < split.length) {
                        if (adjMatrix[s][i] != 1) {
                            adjMatrix[s][i] = 0;
                        }

                        if (split[i].equals("")) {
                            adjMatrix[s][i] = 0;

                        } else {
                            adjMatrix[s][Integer.valueOf(split[i])] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numNodes; j++) {
                    if (adjMatrix[i][j] == 1 && adjMatrix[j][i] == 0) {
                        adjMatrix[j][i] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            conComponents undirectedConnectivity = new conComponents();
            undirectedConnectivity.dfs(adjMatrix);

        }

    } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatch) {
        System.out.println("Wrong Input format");
    }
    sc.close();
}

public void dfs(int adjMatrix[][]) {
    int numNodes = adjMatrix[0].length;
    int visited[] = new int[numNodes];
    int cc = 0;
    for (int vertex = 0; vertex < numNodes; vertex++) {
        if (visited[vertex] == 0) {
            int element = vertex;
            int i = vertex;
            visited[vertex] = 1;
            cc++;
            stack.push(vertex);
            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                element = stack.peek();
                i = element;
                while (i < numNodes) {
                    if (adjMatrix[element][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 0) {
                        stack.push(i);
                        visited[i] = 1;
                        element = i;
                        i = 1;
                        continue;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cc);
}

}
```

Comment: Please provide sample cases where it works and where it doesn't

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but connected components are only defined for _undirected_ graphs.  For general directed graphs, there are _strongly connected components_, but by definition, a DAG has  zero of these (only graphs with cycles have some). You'll have better luck getting a useful answer if you explain what you're actually looking for. Another question is why you'd convert to a matrix? Both connected component and strongly connected component finders are quite easy to implement over adjacency lists. The conversion is a waste of time and space.